# Comparar datos de una misma tabla

Tags: sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla, lo que no se como hacer es una consulta en la cual tanto como a y b tienen un id para Diciembre del 20 y así también un equipo (1 o 2), entonces necesito que ese equipo(1 o 2) si se encuentra en diciembre crear otra columna para ingresar tanto ese 1 o 2 en los valores 0 de Enero del 21

```
| ID | Fecha      | Equipo    
| A  | 01-DEC-20  |     1     
| B  | 01-DEC-20  |    2      
| A  | 01-ENE-21  |     0     
| B  | 01-ENE-21  |     0
```

Comment: Has hecho algo de la consulta? si es asi, compartela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vincular una tabla consigo misma con MySql. Cada fila de la primera tabla se vincula con una fila de la segunda tabla teniendo en cuenta el ID y la Fecha (vincula con la misma fecha pero del mes anterior).

```
SELECT t.*, taux.Equipo AS EquipoAnterior
FROM t
LEFT JOIN t AS taux ON t.ID = taux.ID AND DATE_SUB(t.Fecha, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) = taux.Fecha
ORDER BY t.Fecha, t.ID;
```

En MySql 8.0 podemos obtener un valor (el Equipo) de la fila siguiente (teniendo en cuenta el orden):

```
SELECT *, LEAD(Equipo, 1) OVER (
        PARTITION BY ID
        ORDER BY Fecha DESC) AS EquipoAnterior
FROM t
ORDER BY Fecha, ID;
```

Salida (con los datos de ejemplo que aportaste):

| ID | Fecha | Equipo | EquipoAnterior |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020-12-01 | 1 | null |
| B | 2020-12-01 | 2 | null |
| A | 2021-01-01 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 2021-01-01 | 0 | 2 |

Si quisieras actualizar las filas teniendo en cuenta el Equipo de la fila del mes anterior (siempre y cuando no sea nulo) con el mismo ID.

```
UPDATE t AS x
INNER JOIN t ON  x.ID = t.ID AND DATE_SUB(x.Fecha, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) = t.Fecha
SET x.Equipo = t.Equipo;
```

Comment: Se puede hacer lo mismo sin la necesidad de actualizar la tabla, si no que creando una columna con CASE ??

Comment: Si. Que base de datos estás utilizando?

Comment: Por ejemplo en MySql 8.0 podrías hacer algo así `SELECT *, LEAD(Equipo, 1) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Fecha DESC) AS equipoAnterior FROM t ORDER BY Fecha, ID;`. Hay otras forma de hacerlo también.

Comment: es mysql pero por medio de dbeaver no se si sera la 8.0

Comment: Ahí actualicé la respuesta, con dos formas de hacerlo. Vas a ver que las dos primeras filas tiene valor nulo en la nueva columna, ya que no pueden obtener el valor de las filas anteriores debido a que son las últimas.

Comment: muchas gracias, grande!!!

Comment: De nada! Si te sirvió la respuesta no te olvides de marcarla como aceptada.